# SQL GROUP BY the computed value from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, group-by

I have a table of products which have **price** and **discount** column. I would like to get products grouped by the price (so when 2 products have the same price, it will return only one)

This one works:

```
select * from `products` group by `price` order by `price` asc
```

But my problem is, whether products can be grouped by the computed final price, like (**price - price * discount / 100 as price_after_discount**)

This one:

```
select *, (price - (price * discount / 100)) AS price_after_discount from `products` order by `price_after_discount` asc
```

Returns:

```
[
  0 => [
    "id" => 2284
    "price" => 10.0
    "discount" => 5
    "price_after_discount" => 9.5
  ]
  1 => [
    "id" => 2281
    "price" => 10.0
    "discount" => 0
    "price_after_discount" => 10.0
  ]
  2 => [
    "id" => 2286
    "price" => 10.0
    "discount" => 0
    "price_after_discount" => 10.0
  ]
]
```

As you can see, there are 3 models from which 2 have the same final price.

But when I add the group by statement:

```
select *, (price - (price * discount / 100)) AS price_after_discount from `products` group by `price_after_discount` order by `price_after_discount` asc
```

It returns only this:

```
[
  0 => [
    "id" => 2281
    "price" => 10.0
    "discount" => 0
    "price_after_discount" => 10.0
  ]
]
```

Please, how can I modify the query, so it will return 2 models with ID 2284 and 2281 (or 2286) in this order?

(This is just a transcription of the SQL command that generates Laravel, so anyone who is familiar with Laravel, eloquent or DB facade solution will be appreciate as well :-))

Thank you

Comment: Note that MySQL is giving you a 'random' row for the grouped rows.  This means subsequent operations are **not** guaranteed to give you the same item - you'd need to add some specific column (probably `id`) to the `ORDER BY` to make the results stable.  I'd probably be more worried that you're hiding similar items, though...

Comment: It is even so that all values can be picked arbitrarily per price, so you *might* get the id from one row and the discount from another for instance. (It's just not likely that MySQL does that, as it is usually easier to read it all from one record.)

Comment: I've included some detail on these in my answer; I'm not a heavy MySQL user but I theorize that in the absence of an explicit aggregate, MySQL is just picking one, maybe MIN(). This is dangerous

Answer (score 0):

you said:

```
group by `price_after_discount` order by `price_after_discount`
```

You need to know that GROUP BY operates before(or during) the time that the result set is being calculated, aliased etc, but ORDER BY operates after the result set is created and aliasing of columns is finished. This means that `price_after_discount` is not available as an alias, at the time the database is carrying out your bidding of grouping the data. You have to thus re-state the formula that calculates `price_after_discount` in the group by:

```
select *, (price - (price * discount / 100)) AS price_after_discount 
from `products` 
group by (price - (price * discount / 100))
order by `price_after_discount`
```

Don't be put off by essentially looking like you're running a calculation twice; most DB engines will be smart enough to see the two constructs are identical, they won't run it twice

You could alternatively use some query nesting to encourage the DB engine to do some prep of an aliased resultset first*:

```
select *
from
  (
    select *, (price - (price * discount / 100)) AS price_after_discount 
    from `products` 
  ) as subquery1
group by `price_after_discount`
order by `price_after_discount`
```

Here price_after_discount becomes a part of the subquery before the data is passed to the outer query, and hence it IS available at the grouping time

It may also be helpful to know that this last part will probably end up being a complete lie if you look at what the database does under the hood; better RDBMSes will pick your query apart and look for ways to optimize it. If you were to ask a variety of DBs for a report as to what they did with the two queries here, I don't doubt some of them would produce two plans that are identical, because the optimizer is smart enopugh to realise they're effectively identical. Only pay heed to this last part of my advice if it really interests you, otherwise pick whichever format you feel looks nicer and is easier to understand, if there are no other overriding performance concerns with your particular DB

Further caveat.. I've assumed this is pseudocode, or that your DB is being "helpful" by inserting particular aggregates for all the columns you aren't grouping:

In the typical DBs I work wit day in day out (Oracle, MSSQL) you cannot say:

```
SELECT name, age, social_security_number FROM people GROUP BY name
```

because the DB wants to know what you want to do with all those things you DIDN'T group. Suppose there are two Johns in your table, one 99, the other 14. Which age do you want the DB to return? The 99 or the 14? You're thinking the database has a vested interest in keeping record data together, but all that goes out of the window when GROUP BY is used

Normally we specify what to do with the non-grouped data, with `MAX(age)`, `MIN(Age)`, `SUM(age)` etc..

We have to say to the DB what we want it to do with all the multiple values associated with the common name. If your DB is letting you get away with NOT saying what kind of aggregate to apply, it's probably defaulting to picking some aggregate. There is simply no way it cannot, because GROUP BY is asking it to squash multiple records with duplicate identifiers into one; it's simply not possible to not specify what to do with the other data if you're also demanding the DB return that data to you.

You've said "(so when 2 products have the same price, it will return only one)" - you'll have to tell it which one. In the name example, which is easier to understand because it's contrived and doesn't calculate anything, That would go something like this:

```
SELECT people.* FROM 
  people
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT name, max(age) as maxage FROM people GROUP BY name) as finder
  ON people.name = finder.name AND people.age = finder.age
```

Theres a subquery that gives a list of unique names and the max age for that name. By joining that back to the people data table we can limit the rows we get out of people to only those whose name and max age pairing matches. Essentially this query is "find the oldest people who have a particular name".

What happens when there are two 99 year old Johns? you'll get them both.. so you need a better selector than "I want the oldest of every named person".. Something has to be introduced to break the tie, and added to the query

In your case of prices after discount, if MyQL is just "helping" you out by giving you the MIN() of anything you didn't specify accurately, you could end up with this:

```
[
  0 => [
    "id" => 2281
    "price" => 10.0
    "discount" => 0
    "price_after_discount" => 10.0
  ]
]
```

If your data was this:

```
[
  0 => [
    "id" => 2284
    "price" => 10.0
    "discount" => 5
    "price_after_discount" => 9.5
  ]
  1 => [
    "id" => 2281
    "price" => 20.0
    "discount" => 50
    "price_after_discount" => 10.0
  ]
  2 => [
    "id" => 2287
    "price" => 10.0
    "discount" => 0
    "price_after_discount" => 10.0
  ]
]
```

By grouping on 10.0 discounted price, but just letting MySQL "help" by picking whatever it likes for other values, it's chosen to give you the MIN() of each one, and this has mixed the records up.. It's given 2281 (yes, out of 2281 and 2287, 2281 is the lower number) with a price of 10 (yes, out of 20 and 10, 10 is the lower number) and a discount of 0 (yes, out of 50 and 0, 0 is lower), but now everything is messed: there's no good reason why a database shoudl even keep row data together if it's randomly deciding what to do in the absence of explicit instruction.

It has, however, obeyed correctly to its own rules, it's grouped everything up into "all the 10.0 discounted prices" and then decided to give you the smallest other number of each it could find..

You'll have to decide WHICH product you want and run a query that finds them according to that criteria and returns them:

```
SELECT * FROM 
products
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM products GROUP BY (price - (price * discount/100)) finder
ON finder.id = products.id
```

Hopefully you now know why this works: You ask mysql to prepare you a list of all the highest ID numbers for a particular discounted price. You don't care about passing back the discounted price really (by the way), you just want to do the calc, find the highest ID in the group, and then join it back to the products table to get the rest of the details for that max()ed ID

Comment: Or rap it into some form of subquery, yes.

Comment: Your comment must have beaten my update by seconds there.. Though the original premise is still valid; that at any particular level of nesting, any columns created in the select by calculating something else, are not available to a group by at that nesting level.. They're only available at the next layer out

Comment: Oh, did not know that. Anyway, I rewrote the formula but still the same result with that one model. `select *, (price - (price * discount / 100)) AS price_after_discount from products group by (price - (price * discount / 100)) order by price_after_discount asc`

Comment: "MySQL extends standard SQL to permit aliases" (quote taken from the docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). So OP's query should be valid. (And otherwise I'd have expected an exception, not a wrong result.)

Comment: Thanks TK, that's interesting to know